# Is there a browser event for the window getting focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way that when I click on my browser, and give it focus, to run a method once? And then when the browser loses focus and then gets the focus back to again run that method only once, again.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can attach `focus` and `blur` event handlers on the `window` object to track if the window gets or loses focus (see http://jsfiddle.net/whQFz/ for a trivial example). `window` applies to the current browser context (so that could be a window, a tab, a frame, etc.).

**Note :** The `focus` event will fire every time the window gets focus and the `blur` event will fire every time it loses focus. An example of something that takes focus away from the window is an `alert` window. **If you try to alert in an `onfocus` event handler you'll get an infinite loop of alerts!**

```
// Set global counter variable to verify event instances
var nCounter = 0;

// Set up event handler to produce text for the window focus event
window.addEventListener("focus", function(event) 
{ 
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "window has focus " + nCounter; 
    nCounter = nCounter + 1; 
}, false);

// Example of the blur event as opposed to focus
// window.addEventListener("blur", function(event) { 
// document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "window lost focus"; }, 
// false);
```

Comment: How is it with browser compatibility?

Comment: @TomášFejfar: I tested in IE, Firefox, Chrome and Edge (lastest versions). They all seem too implement this correctly. Hitting `Ctr+F` for search or `Ctrl+T` to open a new tab, all execute the `window.blur()` event for instance.

Comment: One case in which `window.blur()` does not work is when you set a breakpoint in the debugger and it gets hit.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly that's probably by design

Comment: Blur doesn't seem to work on android (at all?). Also, focus only works the first time the window is focused.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_window_focus

Answer (score 19):

```
$(document).ready(function() { $(window).one("focus", SomeFocusMethod); } );

var SomeFocusMethod = function()
{
    // do stuff
    $(window).one("blur", SomeBlurMethod);
}

var SomeBlurMethod = function() 
{ 
    // do stuff
    $(window).one("focus", SomeFocusMethod); 
}
```

Comment: Please include a comment for the downvote as this appears, to me at least, to be an acceptable addition to this question.

Comment: It's not a acceptable answer, as there is no .one() method, there is only an  .on() method, I've corrected you answer.

Comment: There is a 'one' method in jQuery and it is quite handy: https://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Mt]y answer is acceptable and a correct answer. It applies a single time event for each. Obviously circumstances from experience will add to the requirements of the code, but one() as a function is the method to trap the concerned event

Comment: People who haven't seen one probably just thought it was a typo. Your answer is great but only if you don't want this to happen if the user leaves and comes back to focus the window again without rebinding via the chain of one calls.

Answer (score 11):

If you are targeting browsers newer than IE9 you should really use the "Page Visibility API" javascript browser api:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API

Comment: This is not helping for the case for when the browser window is still visible but not in focus.

Answer (score 1):

```
function blinkTab() {
    const browserTitle = document.title;

    const stopBlinking = () => {
        document.title = browserTitle;
    };

    const startBlinking = () => {
        document.title = 'My New Title';
    };

    function registerEvents() {
        window.addEventListener("focus", function(event) { 
            stopBlinking();
        }, false);

        window.addEventListener("blur", function(event) {
            setInterval(() => {
                startBlinking();
            }, 500);

        }, false);
    };

    registerEvents();
};


blinkTab();
```

Comment: I think you need to use clear interval in stopBlinking function