# Is there a way to detect if a component is viewed by the user?

Tags: angular

In my chat application I want to mark the messages with a "is read" flag. But only if the component is alive (means between init and destroy) doesn't really mean that the user has seen it. Since he could be browsing in another tab or minimized the window etc.

So is there any common way to detect if a specific component in angular is displayed on the screen and focused?

Comment: you can use `focus` event...

Comment: I don't think so. The onfocus event works for input fields etc. But that's not what I want..

Comment: How about `window.focus`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3478759/1331040

Comment: I finally found a good library. Gonna update this question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check, whether or not your child component is checked/viewed, then please use **Angular Life Cycle Hooks** in child component.

1. `constructor()`
2. `ngOnChanges()`
3. `ngOnInit()`
4. **`ngDoCheck()`**
5. **`ngAfterContentInit()`**
6. **`ngAfterContentChecked()`**
7. **`ngAfterViewInit()`**
8. **`ngAfterViewChecked()`**.
9. `ngOnDestroy()`

Use the above-highlighted hooks based on your situation.

Please let me know if it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a library which solves this problem: **ngx-page-visibility**

(supports Angular >= 6.x and rxjs >= 6.x)

Here a short demonstration:

```
 @OnPageVisible()
 logWhenPageVisible(): void {
    console.log( 'OnPageVisible' );
    console.log( 'visible' );
 }
```

Or simply do:

```
    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () => {
      if (document.hidden) {
        console.log('document is hidden');
      } else {
        console.log('document is showing');
      }
    });
```